# How can I get the qiskit module

Tags: programming, qiskit

I have successfully installed qiskit. However, when I try to run a simulation I get the error "No module named 'qiskit'

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, execute
```

How can I get or enable this module?

Answer (score 1):

Just install by using pip package 
pip3 install qiskit 
You can find the pip3.exe under the python installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try command `pip install qiskit` or `pip3 install qiskit` in cmd or Anaconda Prompt to install the qiskit module. Then try running the command you used.

If it's still not working check whether your notebook is working in the same location where you installed the qiskit module.

Tip: Use `from qiskit import *` as it saves time and imports all the packages in qiskit.

Alternative: You can also use the jupyter notebook in IBM Quantum Experience.

Comment: Note that the construct `from [package] import *` is considered to be a bad practice in Python as it might imports a **lot** of things into the global namespace and it makes the code less readable (if you have 2 such constructs, someone that does not know the packages have no way of finding which one included the thing he/she is interested in).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a path issue. As already mentioned

```
pip3 install qiskit
```

will install the full package and configure the paths for you.

You can find the search paths for all Python modules by

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If the full path to your Qiskit package is `full/path/to/qiskit` and `'/full/path/to'` is not in `sys.path`, then you need to append it by

```
sys.path.append('full/path/to')
```

in the script you are running. If you are running on Linux, you can write

```
export PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to:$PYTHONPATH
```

in the `.bashrc` file so that you don't need to set the path every time.